# Which map engine is best for S57 maps

Tags: software-recommendations, s-57

I am looking to hear opinions about which is the best offline map engine to display S57 and possible S63 nautical maps.
The map engine supposed to be embedded in our offline application, we need the ability to display only some data from the S57 map and on the fly add our data.

Anyone with experience in this field?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get opinions here, I think. Look for a map system that can read the S57 file format. Many systems rely on the GDAL libraries, which can read S57. Not sure about S63, however

QGIS uses GDAL libraries and can load S-57 files directly. It creates the lines, points and polygons. You will need to set up the styling for each type, however.

This is some river data from [the first place I looked](http://ienccloud.us/ienc_s57.cfm)

[image]

Comment: About S-63 (reasons why not supported) http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Reading-S-63-td5382608.html

Comment: Makes sense. I think the S57 data were proprietary years ago too. The file above was cleared through April 2021, so it's obviously still in use.